# Is there any restriction on selecting path for the MaxFlow problem in datastructure?

Tags: data-structures, max-flow, network-flow

In the following max flow problem, the algorithm could choose `S-A-D-T` path first. In that case, the algorithm will not see any more augmenting paths so it will produce 4 as the answer to the maximum flow. However, if the algorithm would select any other path first, then it would see that the max flow becomes five.

[image: My example graph for maximum flow problem]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not notice that Ford-Fulkerson algorithm updates the residual graph in two ways:

1. subtract path flow from all edges along the selected path
2. add path flow along the reverse edges of the selected path

Therefore after you have selected the `S-A-D-T` path with flow `3`, the residual graph will now contain an augmenting path `S-B-D-A-C-T` with flow `2`, thus reaching a total flow of `5`. Flow along the reverse edges just cancels the existing flow and thus only flow of `2` will remain from `A` to `D`.